# Showing count of content based on the select list values Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I have a requirement in which I need to show some content along with its count based on values in a select list. I wanted to display the allocated,released and resigned resources of a particular department in a selected date range. Using views, date range and department fields are created as exposed filters.

Created a content type for creating resources. The Resources content type is having action as a select list with values allocated,released,resigned. Department is another select list and date field is also added.

Please help me with an answer if views module is not enough. Provide some other solutions also. I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: It's not really clear. Can you provide example, a Mockup or Wireframe of your page?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wanted to build a portal for showing employees in and out of a particular project within a selected date range. I've created resources as a cc and cck select field created for showing the status (allocated,released,resigned). In a view I'm showing date,project  fields as exposed filter and other fields are added. The challenge I'm facing is with showing the count of resources node. if their status value is allocated or released or resigned, I need to take the count accordingly and make some calculations to show if they are in or out for a particular project.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to show node count in views. In my view I’ve some exposed filters and passed my select list cck field as contextual filter. If no result available I made the view to display summary as row count. In the template file, I’m planning to do some calculations for showing the resources count in and out of the project. Please correct me if there is anything wrong in this approach.

Comment: Now I need to show custom select filter inside the views exposed filter to calculate end date from a start date. The select filter is for choosing the number of weeks by users. I tried using hook_views_query alter. But the start date field filter value is not available in conditions array. Date is a pop up. Any help appreciated.